# Could not find default endpoint element that references contract exception while using a WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I created a WCF which later on I converted to SSL(HTTPS)
For which i made some changes in Web config.

I can browse this service and also getting the wsdl for the service.

I  am getting the proper response from service, when hit using HTTPWebrequest Class.

Later i added this service as service Refrence with name NestleServiceRef.
While creating the object of this refrence using

```
 NestleServiceRef.NestleMiddlewareClient nestle = new NestleServiceRef.NestleMiddlewareClient();
```

i am getting this exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'NestleServiceRef.INestleMiddleware' in the ServiceModel client configuration section.
This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName, Configuration configuration)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
   at System.ServiceModel.EndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1 endpointTrait)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor()
   at WebApplication1.NestleServiceRef.NestleMiddlewareClient..ctor() in C:\Users\461167\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Service References\NestleServiceRef\Reference.cs:line 221
   at WebApplication1._Default.Button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\461167\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Default.aspx.cs:line 29}
```

My Web.config file is :

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <section name="NestleMiddlewareWCF.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <membership>
          <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" passwordFormat="Clear" connectionStringName="SQLConnectionString1" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
          </providers>
        </membership>
      </system.web>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="sqliteTemplateName" value="D:\\NestleSQLite\\NestleSqliteTemplate.sqlite" />
        <add key="sqliteFileName" value="D:\\NestleSQLite\\NestleSqliteFile.sqlite" />
        <add key="sqliteConnection" value="Data Source=D:\NestleSQLite\NestleSqliteFile.sqlite;Version=3;New=false;Compress=True" />
        <add key="masterSqliteConnection" value="Data Source=D:\NestleSQLite\NestleSqliteTemplate.sqlite;Version=3;New=false;Compress=True" />
      </appSettings>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SQLConnectionString" connectionString="server=01HW361477;user id=sa;password=DBP@ss;database=IK" />
        <add name="SQLConnectionString1" connectionString="server=01HW361477;user id=sa;password=DBP@ss;database=IK" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
          <service name="NestleMiddlewareWCF.NestleMiddleware" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
            <endpoint address="https://10.137.243.130:12345/NestleMiddleware.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="NestleMiddlewareWCF.INestleMiddleware" behaviorConfiguration="web" />
          </service>
        </services>
          <bindings>
              <webHttpBinding>
                  <binding name="webBinding">
                      <security mode="Transport">       </security>
                  </binding>
              </webHttpBinding>
          </bindings>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">

              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl="https://10.137.243.130:12345/NestleMiddleware.svc/mex" />
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="web">
              <webHttp />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
      </system.serviceModel>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
      </system.webServer>
      <applicationSettings>
        <NestleMiddlewareWCF.Properties.Settings>
          <setting name="NestleMiddlewareWCF_CopyService_Copy" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://01hw361477:4880/_vti_bin/copy.asmx</value>
          </setting>
        </NestleMiddlewareWCF.Properties.Settings>
      </applicationSettings>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: I see a password, is it fake?

Comment: FYI, one would say, "a WCF service", not "a WCF".

Answer (score 0):

You need to share the  section of the client's config file, the error is reported there and the web.config above looks to be the service host's config (or it has no client section, which is the problem).